# Is there anyway to develop iPad Apps in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ipad

Just not a fan of Xcode, is there like any chance?

Has anyone tried it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

last i checked, the iPad doesn't run Java apps. if you're developing HTML/CSS/Javascript apps, yes. You can use Aptana. If not, you're better off working with Xcode

Comment: last i checked, Eclipse doesn't always mean Java

Comment: touche. however, the question was edited after i answered, so i might have answered based on the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to develop native iPad application. If yes, there is no way developing iPad application using Objective-C with Eclipse.